# BOOST directory on windows

Tags: boost, vcpkg

I used **vcpkg** to install boost, but now that I need the install directory to compile something, I have no idea where it is. Here's what I installed:

```
vcpkg install boost-iostreams:x64-windows
vcpkg install boost-any:x64-windows
vcpkg install boost-algorithm:x64-windows
vcpkg install boost-uuid:x64-windows
vcpkg install boost-interprocess:x64-windows
```

[image: packages folder of vcpkg]

which one of this is the install directory?

Also here's is the line where I need to set the directory:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=%DEPS_DIR%\boost_1_67_0
```

I know this is a basic question, but i couldn't find an answer. Thank you